# ContentRootPath of hosting environment in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core

I am creating an ASP Core web Application with Linux docker enabled. I need to get the proper ContentRootPath from the hosting environment to process this further.

In normal ASP Web Application, the local path is returned as "D:\Sample\WebApplication1" whereas in Linux, it is returned as "/app".

Can anyone please suggest on how to get the exact local path in Linux Docker application?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the working directory option in docker file
WORKDIR /app to whatever location you want

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to change the working directory with the docker file of a single application like WORKDIR /D://Sample//WebApplication1  but this doesn't affect the hosting environment.  Whether this has to be done only using command. Please provide a suggestion on this.

Comment: Also tried the same with command "docker run -w /D:/sample/webapplication1/ -i -t  linux pwd" but this throws me an error " pull access denied for linux, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied."